# How to insert yesterday's date in the email's subject using xml?

Tags: xml, date, html-email

```
<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <From>xxx@yyy.com</From> <!--Must be valid email-->

    <To>xxx@yyy.com</To> <!--Must be valid email-->

    <CC>xxx@yyy.com</CC> <!--Must be valid email-->

    <Subject>The report is for  </Subject> <!--Must be yesterday's date-->

<Message>D:\Msg.txt</Message> <!--Set the email content-->

</Config>
```

This is code that i am using to fill in the email details & i would like to get yesterday's date in the subject.

Comment: You want to edit the subject node to append the yesterday date, that's it ?

Comment: Yes, a function to return yesterday's date in the Subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) to edit the file in place :

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -u '//Subject' \
    -v "The report is for $(date -d yesterday '+%m %d %Y')" file.xml
```